# Return auto generated IDs when child_added listener is called

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following data structure in my `firebase` database:

[image]

I've added a `child_added` method, which returns all entries from `firebase` when the application is run and then displays them on a `HTML` table.

Issue I have is, it's not returning the auto generated Id's for each bug.

This is my method:

```
 getAddedBugs(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(obs => {
        this.bugsDbRef.on('child_added', bug => {
            const newBug = bug.val() as Bug;
            obs.next(newBug);
        },
            err => {
                obs.throw(err)
            });
    });
}
```

The `class` `Bug` looks like this:

```
export class Bug {
 constructor(
     public id: string,
     public title: string,
     public description: string,
     public status: number,
     public severity: number,
     public createdBy: string,
     public createdDate: number,
     public updatedBy?: string,
     public updatedDate?: number
  ) {}
}
```

So then question is, how can I get my method to also include the auto generated Id's, as I'll need this Id to update / delete etc.

I've googled this and unfortunately I've not been able to find anything on this.

Can someone shed some light into how I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than casting the event's snapshot's value to a `Bug` (it's not a `Bug`; it's just an `Object`), you should create a `Bug` instance using the information from the snapshot. The snapshot contains the key (the auto generated ID) and the value:

```js
getAddedBugs(): Observable<any> {
  return Observable.create(obs => {
    this.bugsDbRef.on('child_added',
      snapshot => {
        // The snapshot's value will be an Object, not a Bug instance.
        const val = snapshot.val();
        const bug = new Bug(
          snapshot.key, // The auto generated ID.
          val.title,
          val.description,
          ... etc.
        );
        obs.next(bug);
      },
      err => {
        obs.throw(err)
      });
    });
}
```

You should also consider returning a function that removes the event listener upon unsubscription:

```js
getAddedBugs(): Observable<any> {
  return Observable.create(obs => {
    const listener = snapshot => {
      const val = snapshot.val();
      const bug = new Bug(
        snapshot.key,
        val.title,
        val.description,
        ... etc.
      );
      obs.next(bug);
    }
    this.bugsDbRef.on('child_added', listener, err => { obs.throw(err) });
    return () => this.bugsDbRef.off('child_added', listener);
  });
}
```